# Incomplete result when passing asynchronous method to Action parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am not sure whether this kind of problem has been asked before. I am learning asynchronous method.

`JobAsync` is a trivial example of asynchronous methods, `Do` accepts a delegate of type `Action`, and `Main` just calls the `Do` which in turn call `JobAsync` via an asynchronous lambda. See my code below for the details.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task JobAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin JobAsync");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("End JobAsync");
    }

    static void Do(Action a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Do");
        a();
        Console.WriteLine("End Do");
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Main");
        Do(async () => await JobAsync());
        Console.WriteLine("End Main");
    }
}
```

In the output below,

> Begin Main
>
> Begin Do
>
> Begin JobAsync
>
> End Do
>
> End Main

The `End JobAsync` does not exist.

## Question

What causes this phenomenon in which the `End JobAsync` does not exist in the output?

Any suggestions or comments are always welcome! If `Do` is from a third party library, how can we know that we cannot pass an asynchronous method to it?

## Edit

Is the rule of thumb "Don't pass asynchronous methods as arguments of  type other than `Func<...,Task` or `Func<...,Task<...>>` of non asynchronous methods?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your async method returns a Task, so you should be using `Func<Task>` instead of `Action`. You then have to await the task.

```
static async Task Do(Func<Task> a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin Do");
    await a();  //Notice we await the result here
    Console.WriteLine("End Do");
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, an `await` without an `async`?